# Securing mail account when mailing with ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, security, email

As far as I know we have to write a mail account for sending mails in ASP.NET: username, host, port, password. Is there a way to encrypt that or secure it somehow other than owning a server? Otherwise everyone who has privilage to see files on that computer is able to see the account data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [Sean's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19031258/304683).

This is just to clarify your statement about *"having to write mail account.."*

- You will need to do so one way or the other so your app knows where the MTA is and how to authenticate to it (if/when required).
- Encrypting sections of web.config as Sean stated is the way to go, and gives you flexibility, but it's *not the only way*. You *can* [do same in code](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2766967/304683) - so if you precompile your code (dll) it mitigates your concern about file system access.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to encrypt sections of your web.config file and you can also store your SMTP settings in the web.config file.

SMTP settings in web.config look like this:

```
<configuration>
    ...
    <system.net>
        <mailSettings>
            <smtp from="user@domain.com" deliveryMethod="Network">
                <network host="smtp.domain.com" port="25" userName="user@domain.com" password="password" />
            </smtp>
        </mailSettings>
    </system.net>
    ...
</configuration>
```

Microsoft article on encrypting web.config files and accessing the encrypted data: http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/dtkwfdky.aspx