# Cannot implicitly convert type ('string', 'string') to System.Net.ICredentialsByHost

Tags: c#, .net, email, system.net.mail

So i tried making an email sender and give my account info and this error showed up:

> Cannot implicitly convert type ('string', 'string') to System.Net.ICredentialsByHost.

This is the code.

```
SmtpClient SmtpServer = new SmtpClient("smpt.gmail.com", 587);

SmtpServer.Credentials = ("username", "password"); # The email and password were lighted up with red
MailMessage Mail = new MailMessage();
Mail.From = new MailAddress("from");
```

I changed the email and password for obvious reasons.

Comment: The part `= ("username", "password")` looks wrong. Did you [read the documentation of `SmtpClient.Credential`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.mail.smtpclient.credentials)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are trying to convert a `ValueTuple` to `ICredentialsByHost`. Need to construct a new NetworkCredential instance and set it in SmtpServer:

```
NetworkCredential credentials = new NetworkCredential("username", "password");  
SmtpServer.Credentials = credentials;
```

Answer (score 0):

The `SmtpServer.Credentials` property needs an object that interface from the `ICredentialsByHost` interce. `("username", "password")` can't be implicitly converted to an object that `ICredentialsByHost` interface.

You could use the `NetworkCredential` class like this

```cs
SmtpServer.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("username", "password");
```

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2766967/3506115)